# add an IPTables entry on Linux to let out Redis

Tags: linux, windows, iptables, linux-networking, redis

On my Windows machine Client (name it `WIN`) I installed a VirtualBox Ubuntu Linux Mint Redis Server (name it `LS`), attached to the local network as Bridged Adapter.

[image]

On my `LS` I have

```
$ hostname -I
10.14.30.51 

$ ps -aux | grep redis
avahi      647  0.0  0.1   6164  3072 ?        Ss   10:14   0:03 avahi-daemon: running [redis-server.local]
redis     2048  0.1  0.1  39772  3532 ?        Ssl  10:23   0:26 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379
root      2471  0.0  0.0   5312   868 pts/0    S+   14:27   0:00 grep --color=auto redis

$ redis-cli ping
PONG
```

in the `/etc/redis/redis.conf` file I commented out the `bind 127.0.0.1 ::1` line...

But actually the connections from the Windows machine aren't working...
I suppose I need to add something to the LS `iptables`, but not sure what exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Check the listen address with `ss -tlnp 'sport == :6379'`. If you will see `127.0.0.1` or `::1` in these lines, you've forgotten restart redis after changing of the configuration. If you see something like `0.0.0.0:6379`, follow the next step.
- Check the `protected mode` of redis.
- Check the output `iptables-save -c`. Order of rules is very important. To allow incoming connection to redis, you should add rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT \
         --src <allowed-ip> \
         -p tcp --dport 6379 \
    -j ACCEPT
```

Sure, you can allow connections from any ip address, but this isn't a good idea.

Comment: first point, I see both 127 and ::1, I restarted the redis, and I have now only 0.0.0.0 and [::]

Comment: `protected-mode yes`, but what is the "allowed IP", is it the Windows machine IP?

Comment: actually I added my windows machine IP on the linux IPTables, and ut seems the nmap on windows see the port 6379 OPEN on the Linux machine! Thanks a lot!